# Mobile Web App Photo Uploads

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, web-applications, photos

Here is our situation:
We have a Web App built on `.NET framework` using `HTML5` and `javascript` to handle client side data processing. There is also a back end of a Web SQL database (yes-deprecated, in the process to transitioning to `WebStorage` and this is part of that process) that holds all of the form data so that data is accessible offline.  There is a sync button that will upload all of the data to our server (via web method and data adapters).  I can provide more details if necessary but that is the gist of the situation.

I want to know the best way to handle photo uploads.  We use `HTML5`

```
 <input type='file'>
```

and

```
 <input type='file' multiple='multiple'>
```

to access the file system (photos) and "store" them.

My idea is to store the file location in the database, and then execute the uploads when Sync is pressed, but i'm not sure that is possible on `iOS` and/or `Android`.  If this solution is possible, can someone point me in the right direction?  If not then i'd like to hear ideas on the best way to achieve this without storing the entire photo file in the `Web SQL database`.